# How do I run an Envoy Task with a tty?

Tags: sudo, tty, laravel-envoy

I'm using Laravel's Envoy library for deployment. When I get to the end of deployment, I need to change a bunch of files' ownership; in order to do this, I need to switch to the root user, because `chown` and `chmod` don't work as an unprivileged user.

How do I get Envoy to run a specific server using a tty so that `sudo chown ...` will work?

[Here's a link to my Envoy.blade.php file.](http://pastebin.com/8H6QEHp8)

Answer (score 4):

I used the following code to run privileged commands through envoy. I'll give a chown example but add what you want after -S

```
@task('mytask', ['on' => 'myserver'])
    echo "{{ $password}}" | sudo -S chown 644 /myfile
@endtask
```

And run with

```
envoy run mytask --password=mypass
```